# volume distribution in rolling window

Tags: javascript, arrays, mathematical-optimization, moving-average, rolling-computation

I would like to have volume distribution per day in 7 days window.

For example for 1st week:

- during Monday I get 4 items of 1 in various times,
- on Tuesday 3 items of 1 etc

and accordingly state changes.

| Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 3 | 5 | 0 | 4 | 3 | 1 |

But the problem is when 2nd week comes, I would like that Monday starts from 0 (and continue with sum), and that other days are preserved, also the same for other days, when new Tuesday comes it starts from 0...etc. Is there any clever way to do this?

I can easily identify the "bin" where item needs to land with modulo operator, but I cannot think of some way to know when exactly each day need to start from 0 because "new Monday" has arrived (and continue to sum up Monday with new items).

Answer (score 3):

Could be problems with daylight saving as I am using timestamp, this I have doubts. But this seems working. If some of code seems strange, this is probably as it is worked to fit with solidity which does not have all the nice feats of javascript.
Goal is to get sum of volumes in last 7 days from specific date:

```
class rollingWindow {
      constructor() {
        this.refTime = new Date("01/01/2023 00:00:00");
        // bins - days of the week (starting from Sunday)
        this.distribution = {
          0: { vol: 0, week: 0 },
          1: { vol: 0, week: 0 },
          2: { vol: 0, week: 0 },
          3: { vol: 0, week: 0 },
          4: { vol: 0, week: 0 },
          5: { vol: 0, week: 0 },
          6: { vol: 0, week: 0 }
        };
      }
    }
    
    rollingWindow.prototype.add = function (volume, datetime) {
      let diff = (datetime.getTime() - this.refTime.getTime());
      let bin = (diff / 1000/60/60/24)  % 7;
bin = bin - (bin % 1); // floor function
     console.log("bin:" + bin); // day of the week
     
      const floorargm = diff / (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
      let currentWeek = floorargm - (floorargm % 1)
    
    
      console.log("Week:"+currentWeek);
    
      if (this.distribution[bin].week < currentWeek) {
        this.distribution[bin].vol = 0;
        this.distribution[bin].week = currentWeek;
      }
      this.distribution[bin].vol += volume;
    };
    
    rollingWindow.prototype.get = function(datetime) {
      let diff = (datetime.getTime() - this.refTime.getTime());
      let bin = (diff / 1000/60/60/24)  % 7;
bin = bin - (bin % 1); // floor function
      const floorargm = diff / (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
      let currentWeek = floorargm - (floorargm % 1);
    
      // sum left bins and current bin
      let sum=0;
      for (let i = bin; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (this.distribution[i].week === currentWeek) {
            sum+= this.distribution[i].vol;
        }
        if(i === 0) {
          break;
        }
      }
      // sum right bins
      for (let i = bin + 1; i < 7;i++) {
        if (this.distribution[i].week === currentWeek - 1) {
          sum+= this.distribution[i].vol;
        }
      }
    
      return sum;
    }
    let rolling = new rollingWindow()
    
    rolling.add(1, new Date("01/01/2023 00:00:00"));
    rolling.add(1, new Date("01/02/2023 00:00:00"));
    rolling.add(1, new Date("01/02/2023 00:00:00"));
    rolling.add(1, new Date("01/03/2023 00:00:00"));
    rolling.add(1, new Date("01/04/2023 00:00:00"));
    rolling.add(1, new Date("01/05/2023 00:00:00"));
    rolling.add(1, new Date("01/06/2023 00:00:00"));
    rolling.add(1, new Date("01/07/2023 00:00:00"));
    rolling.add(1, new Date("01/08/2023 00:00:00"));
    
    let sum = rolling.get(new Date("01/08/2023 00:00:00"));
    
    
    console.log(sum);
```